# MyLabel's Caption of TCustomLabel is not changing

Tags: delphi, properties, caption, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have created a component `TMyLabel` which inherits from `TCustomLabel`.

I want to add periods at the end of the `Caption` if a Boolean property `SetPeriodAtEnd` is set to True, and remove periods if it is set to False.

I have declared the Boolean property:

```
property SetPeriodAtEnd: Boolean read fPeriodAtEnd write SetPeriodAtEnd;
```

```
procedure TMyLabel.SetPeriodAtEnd(Value: Boolean);
begin
  fPeriodAtEnd := Value;
  if fPeriodAtEnd then
    Caption := Caption + '.......';
end;
```

This works when `SetPeriodAtEnd()` is changed only once. Later `......` gets added even for a False value.

Also, my motive was to add periods `......` only in `Caption` for viewing and not as value. For example, `Caption := hello....` for viewing and store `Caption` as `hello` without periods. Is this possible?

Can select different font style and color for only cDots?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you post your code? Without the code it is difficult to understand what you are doing and hence why it is not working

Comment: `Caption :=caption` has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are attempting to do, you can override the virtual [`GetLabelText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomLabel.GetLabelText) method:

> Returns the value of the `Caption` property.
>
> Call GetLabelText to **obtain the string that appears as the text of the label**.

Internally, `TCustomLabel` uses `GetTextLabel()` when drawing its `Caption`, and when resizing itself when the `Caption` changes and `AutoSize` is true.  So, you can override `GetLabelText()` to provide a different string than what the `Caption` is set to, eg:

```pascal
type
  TMyLabel = class(TCustomLabel)
  private
    fPeriodAtEnd: Boolean;
    procedure SetPeriodAtEnd(Value: Boolean);
  protected
    function GetLabelText: string; override;
  published
    property SetPeriodAtEnd: Boolean read fPeriodAtEnd write SetPeriodAtEnd;
  end;

...

uses
  System.StrUtils;

function TMyLabel.GetLabelText: string;
const
  cDots = '.......';
begin
  Result := inherited GetLabelText;
  if fPeriodAtEnd then
  begin
    if not EndsText(cDots, Result) then
      Result := Result + cDots;
  end
  else begin
    if EndsText(cDots, Result) then
      Result := LeftStr(Result, Length(Result)-Length(cDots));
  end;
end;

procedure TMyLabel.SetPeriodAtEnd(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if fPeriodAtEnd <> Value then
  begin
    fPeriodAtEnd := Value;
    Perform(CM_TEXTCHANGED, 0, 0); // triggers Invalidate() and AdjustBounds()
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Remy. I will try this out.

Comment: this worked.. Thank you.. can we change font.style of the dots?

Comment: Can I select different font style and color only for cDots?

Comment: For that, you would have to override the label's `Paint()` method and draw the caption text manually. Then you can split the text as desired and draw the substrings using different font settings